# C# run tesseract (or any command) in Linux

Tags: c#, linux, tesseract

I have a C# wrapper to run Tesseract, and it works fine under Windows.  I look at the registry entries and get the installation directory in order to run Tesseract.exe.  I would like to know how could I do the same, as I'm porting my code with .Net Core 3.1 to Linux.  My code to set the Tesseract info for Windows is:

```
private bool SetTesseractInfo(string dataDir = null)
    {
        try
        {
            //using (RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Computer\\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Tesseract-OCR"))
            using (RegistryKey key = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64).OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Tesseract-OCR"))
            {
                if (key != null)
                {
                    Object o = key.GetValue("Path");
                    if (o != null)
                    {
                        _tesseractExePath = Path.Combine(o.ToString(), "tesseract.exe");

                        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(dataDir))
                            dataDir = Path.Combine(o.ToString(), "tessdata");

                        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("TESSDATA_PREFIX", dataDir);
                    }

                    o = key.GetValue("CurrentVersion");
                    if (o != null)
                        _tesseractVersion = o.ToString();
                }
                else
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is your problem, to find tesseract or to launch it? Your question title differs a lot with what your question body seems to ask.

Comment: To find Tesseract and Launch it, so I guess both

Comment: You launch it like in WIndows, `Process.Start`. To find it, don't think you need to, binaries will be installed in `/usr/bin/` and will be available in any path.

Comment: Thanks!! I will try that out and will let you know.  I might have installed Tesseract incorrectly, which may be why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use existing [.NET Tesseract wrapper](https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract) (e.g. via [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Tesseract/4.1.0-beta1)). It properly launches OCR on Linux or Mac.

By the way, it does not depend on installed Tesseract.exe. Instead, it runs OCR using .NET bindings for libtesseract and libleptonica libraries. You can look at implementation of [TesseractEngine.cs](https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract/blob/master/src/Tesseract/TesseractEngine.cs)

Here is configuration steps for Ubuntu 20.04:

```
cd ~/YourProject/x64 # Place "x64" directory on the same level with "tessdata"

sudo apt install libleptonica-dev
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblept.so.5 libleptonica-1.78.0.so

sudo apt install libtesseract-dev
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtesseract.so.4.0.1 libtesseract41.so
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response Vitaly.  I would like to know if there are documented steps to compile using a newer version of Tesseract.

Comment: Do you mean 5.0-alpha? I did not try to compile it but the process should be the same as for previous version: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/tree/5.0.0-alpha. Tesseract 5.0 does not require special tessdata so data files from v 4.0 will work.

The latest stable version is Tesseract 4.1.1 and .NET wrapper supports it just fine. Use this package if you are interested in Tesseract 4.1: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Tesseract/4.1.0-beta1

Comment: sir, you are beyond helpful! thank you so very much.

Comment: Glad to help you! You can upvote and accept the answer if you find it useful.

Comment: I've been trying to do that, but it keeps telling me my reputation is too low for that!

Answer (score 0):

Resolve by  this commands in Docker file

- ln -s /usr/lib/libleptonica.so.6.0.0 /app/ProjectName/x64/libleptonica-1.82.0.so
- ln -s /usr/lib/libtesseract.so.5.0.3 /app/ProjectName/x64/libtesseract50.so
- ln -s /app/ProjectName/tessdata/eng.traineddata /usr/share/tessdata/eng.traineddata